# get the value of input text in a directive (ANGULAR.JS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://jsfiddle.net/ccLwj3us/

Hi. this is my code. I need get the value of the input text, but I only can get the value, when the value on the input text ischanged. How can get the value of the input text without need change.(get initially the value of the input text)

I want to do something very generic, that I can reuse it in any controller. Have a certain number of fields and validate them, so I do not want to always get the value of the variable "number".

I want to reuse this directive on any controller. I will not always have the $ scope.numero variable. How can I get the value of the text field without typing scope.numero in the directive?

```
  var app = angular.module('app', []);

  app.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.numero=100500
  });

  app.directive('validate', function () {

      return {
          restrict: 'AE',
          require: 'ngModel', 

          link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel){
              return;          
            }

            ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val){
              if ((val>10) && (val<20)){
                element.removeClass("wrong"); 
                element.addClass("correct"); 
              } else {
                element.removeClass("correct");
                element.addClass("wrong"); 
              }
              ngModel.$render();
            })


          }
      };
  });
```

Comment: you want to get the value of numero in your directive, when you are initializing it?

Comment: @Pramod_Para yes, i need this value but in the directive for check the validation to assign error | correct class

Comment: @Pramod_Para I want to do something very generic, that I can reuse it in any controller. Have a certain number of fields and validate them, so I do not want to always get the value of the variable "number"

Comment: Did you try setting an attribute and getting value in directive?

Comment: This is what I need, get the "value" attribute of the field

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2tmxaL8y/ check this, i have updated your fiddle

Comment: @Pramod_Para Thank you very much, but I want to reuse this directive on any controller. I will not always have the $ scope.numero variable. How can I get the value of the text field without typing scope.numero in the directive?

Comment: Use `ngModel.$modelValue`.  (Also it is not safe to set DOM attributes directly from a controller; use scope variables and `ng-class` instead.)

Comment: I have updated the fiddle again, please check http://jsfiddle.net/7hph3pa5/, you can access with attrs.something

Comment: You can also try what @DanielBeck has suggested, it works like a charm!

Comment: @DanielBeck it not works, for me.. http://jsfiddle.net/0tsvue0L/

Comment: The data hasn't arrived yet.  Wrap that alert in a `$timeout` and you'll see the correct value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you need is already inside the `ngModel`, so you can retrieve it with `ngModel.$modelValue`.

(In general, when using Angular it's best to get out of the habit of reading data from the DOM -- the DOM is a side effect representation of the scope data; there's no need for the directive to "read the data from the input field" because the input field was filled using data already in the directive in the first place!)

Comment: thanks man, but  the result of ngModel.$modelValue is NaN.. jsfiddle.net/0tsvue0L

Comment: You're trying to access the data before it's reached the directive.  Wrap that alert in a `$timeout` (to force it to wait until the next `$digest`) and you'll see the correct value: http://jsfiddle.net/tL4b13o6/